# Momentum and photon indistinguishability

Tags: quantum-mechanics, interference, quantum-optics, identical-particles

Suppose two photons have the same frequency and polarization, and their wavepackets also have identical temporal and spatial (along their propagation directions, respectively) profiles.
The two photons propagate towards a detector at different angles, i.e., their momentums are different. Can they interfere quantum mechanically like indistinguishable photons.

Usually, we label a state by its momentum and energy, so states with different momentum or energy are considered distinguishable. Here I would like to consider such "distinguishability" approaching zero.

For example, if there is a small deviation between the energy of the two photons, they can still interfere quantum mechanically at some level. This is calculated through an overlap integral of their frequency spectra.
On the other hand, momentum of a photon is pointing along a well-defined direction, i.e., the distribution of one photon's momentum along all directions is usually a delta function.

How to consider the quantum mechanical interference between two photons with small deviation between their momentums?

- The two-photon interference here refers to the [Hong–Ou–Mandel effect](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.59.2044).

Comment: Photons do not have a frequency or polarization. They have energy, momentum and angular momentum.

Comment: I would suggest being careful with the word "indistinguishable," which you use in two different senses in your question.  When we call a collection of particles *indistinguishable*, it means that any physical state (not necessarily *wavefunction*, but **state**) is invariant under the interchange of any two particles.  It is an intrinsic property of the collection of particles which doesn't depend on precisely which single-particle states are occupied and which are not.  That is what you refer to in your first paragraph, "[...] like indistinguishable photons."  Later you indicate that [...]

Comment: [...] you call two photons distinguishable if they do not occupy precisely the same state.  This is a totally different sense of the word (in)distinguishable.

Answer (score 1):

Typically the beamsplitters in this experiment are fed by fibres which in turn are fed by BBO crystals generating entangles pairs of photons.  While the fibres and lenses can accommodate a range of angles the BBO crystal produces the pairs in identical angles ... with the exception that delay lines will affect the incoming angle of one of the photons.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6140626/ shows a typical setup.

If the angle(s) become to large then reflection will can occur, however the answer to your question is yes to some degree.  In the link above the combining of the quanta ("constructive interference") occurs as the delay becomes small, this delay affects both timing and angle.

Answer (score 0):

I have a slightly different interpretation than @AnnaV. In my view the electromagnetic wave is a wave function, like Schrödinger's, that describes the probability of detecting photons and with specific energy, momentum and angular momentum.

With this in mind the answer is that you first calculate the electromagnetic wave function for your problem. Here interference comes in play. Armed with the result, you can then predict where you can detect which type of photon.

In your case you speak of two photons. This suggests that there are two sources. These sources are very likely incoherent. In this case you should not add the amplitudes of the em waves but the intensity. That is, there is no interference.

Answer (score 0):

> if there is a small deviation between the energy of the two photons, they can still interfere quantum mechanically at some level. This is calculated through an overlap integral of their frequency spectra.

This is correct. An identical situation is in place if you replace energy with momentum.

In particular, your assertion that

> the momentum of a photon is pointing along a well-defined direction

is not really correct. Photons only have a well-defined direction if they are in plane-wave states that occupy all of space (and which are obviously not physical), in the same way that they only have a well-defined energy if they are excitations of monochromatic modes of infinite duration (which are not physical either). For any realistic photon in a real-world experiment, there will be a nonzero momentum uncertainty, and two photons can indeed interfere (partially) if the overlap between their momentum-space wavefunctions is nonzero.

Comment: Would photons that have "constructively interfered" in the Hong-Ou-Mandel affect retain any of their original angle properties ?  or do they emerge fully in phase and in direction similar to a laser?

Answer (score -1):

In mainstream elementary particle physics, a photon is a point particle , of fixed energy and momentum, and no space extension. The $ν$ in $E=hν$   is the frequency of the classical electromagnetic wave which may be built up with photons of that energy.

The wavepacket concept is irrelevant, for single photons, there are no profiles. It is true that due to Quantum mechanics the emission and absorption lines have a width, and so the energy of the photons does not have to be an exact number to be absorbed or emitted, but that is a different story, of atomic states and photon emission and absorption.

> The two photons propagate towards a detector at different angles, i.e., their momentums are different. Can they interfere quantum mechanically like indistinguishable photons.

Whether of different energy or the same, the [two photon interaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-photon_physics) occurs in a very small volume of space and depends on the coupling constant elecrtromagnetic interactions. Once the photons move from the interaction point, they are independent point particles.

As explained above this is no correct,

> For example, if there is a small deviation between the energy of the two photons, they can still interfere quantum mechanically at some level. This is calculated through an overlap integral of their frequency spectra.

> How to consider the quantum mechanical interference between two photons with small deviation between their momentums?

There is none, as two photon interacions have very small probability even at head on scattering.